# Free Jquery slider with the images showing on the sides?

Tags: jquery, plugins

Does anyone know a jQuery slider plugin with the images showing on the sides like this?

[image]

I couldn't find it on Google.

Comment: Can you provide website's URL?

Comment: The slider is no longer there. jayholliwood.com

Comment: Does this help? http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/12/jquery-carousel.html

Comment: @aug could you post it as a answer so I can check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific thing you are looking for is **JQuery Carousel** Hope this helps :) It has a list of a bunch of them!

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/12/jquery-carousel.html

Quickly updating this answer regarding carousels. For those interested, I don't believe they are very good practice to have anymore -- they still are nice but right now minimalism and scrolling are favored for UI and having users click to go through images is too tedious.

Funny site: http://shouldiuseacarousel.com/

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean free or paid?

Here is one for $4 from CodeCanyon.

http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-carousel-evolution/full_screen_preview/490018

Answer (score 1):

http://www.bkosborne.com/jquery-feature-carousel

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

those two should help you get what you want done ! i didnt think it would be hard to find with `jquery` 
 and by the way they are called `carousel`

Answer (score 0):

Free Option:

Here I found Two pages the developer page I think!? Perhaps?!

http://www.catchmyfame.com/catchmyfame-jquery-plugins/jquery-infinite-carousel-plugin/

A functioning demo

http://www.catchmyfame.com/jquery/infinitecarousel3/demo/d3.html

And one site with the pluging

http://www.insidepublicidad.com/slider/index.html

Here you go! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout

Roundabout is highly-customizable with an extensive API that allows for some pretty amazing results.

Demo at :

http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/demos/standard

Answer (score 0):

I Hope it'll help you

http://css-tricks.com/moving-boxes/

You can modify style as per you need.