# Free jQuery slider with prev and next image sliding out to the side?

Tags: jquery, plugins

Basically, it would look like this:

[image]

I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640473/free-jquery-slider-with-the-images-showing-on-the-sides) before, but I could only find "rotators": the images rotate instead of sliding to the side.

Does anyone know a plugin with this feature?